# SQLite id row not following sequential order after deleting rows

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to make a notes taking app and the way I wrote app to delete specific row is in this way -

**FIRST -** If a user taps on any cardView from a recyclerView, first activity will forwards cardView position using getAdapterPosition().

**SECOND -** Second activity receives cardView`s positon, to delete a specific row from SQLite database, I called a method known as 'totalNotes()' which will return total number of rows present in SQLite database. Finally, to delete the row I subtract the number received from 'totalNotes()' method with the getAdapterPosition().

**PROBLEM -** They way I have programmed it only works if the rows in the database are in sequential order. However, when a user wants to delete a row number 3 and 2 from 5 rows, the remaning rows are 1,4 and 5. How can make the database so auto implement sequential order after row deletion?

I have looked on 'almost' similar problem on the site but they fail when I try to implement in my code. I am new to Android development.

[Demo Picture][2]

How can I assign sequential IDs?

[How my app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95lG4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not base on the row number sequential. Almost(if not all) all databases have the same behavior on auto-increment field. When you get data from database you need to get also the ID, and to keep the ID inside the APP so when deleting from DB you will delete base on that ID:

```
id = note.noteID;  /// Selected note (noteID) to be deleted. 

--------

dbHandler!!.deleteNote(id);

---------

// Here you bind your note to your viewHolder
fun bindItems(note: UserNotes) {
    noteTitle.text = note.noteTitle
    noteText.text = note.noteText
    noteText.noteId = note.noteID;

}
```

Comment: Could you please be more elaborate? I have added a code that reads ID as well. I will post my codes here.

Comment: I edited the answer. When you select the card to delete, you pass not the position in list, but the noteID, and you use that ID to delete it from database.

Comment: If you look at my MAIN_ACTIVITY code inside for loop as well as PEDIA_DATABASE`s readAllNotes(), I am fetching IDs as well.  I am confused because I do not understand how am I going to fetch corresponding data without getAdapterPosition() when a cardView is clicked

Comment: The same way you do with noteText and noteTitle, you can do with noteID, and pass it to the intent. You use class ViewHolder for that.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what you mean. Do I have to use noteID = getItemID() ?

Comment: First of all , you do not hold anywhere the noteID, this why i showed you where and how to store, next, when item is selected you need to take that noteText.noteId and pass to intent.

Answer (score 0):

Using sequential Ids is bad, because when you delete a record with `Id = 5`, the next record you add to your table is not going to be `Id = 5` as well, it's going to be `Id = 6`, so it's going to cause you problems sooner or later.

The way @Simion suggested is:

1. You ask for all the data, (i.e. all your notes)
2. When you select a note you ask for the `Id` of that note, and save it in a variable.
3. If the user decides to delete that note you should do `deleteNote(noteId)`, that way you can use anything you want as an `Id` and you don't rely on the `Ids` being sequential (which is, as I said before, usually a bad idea)

Comment: To remove sequential ID, I have to remove 'KEY_ID' "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"? One more thing I dont understand is that how do I know which specific cardView was clicked and how to get that cardView`s corresponding ID?